# Xpath definition for alert message

Tags: java, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I have defined an xpath to create the webelement(alertMessage) for the message text: "User doesn't exist."

With the firepath it says the xpath is : xpath = ".//*[@id='loginAlert']"

```
<div id="login-box">
<h1>Control Sphere Login</h1>
<form id="login" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" name="login" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<div id="input-box">
<div id="submit-box">
<div id="loginAlert" class="loginAlert">User doesn't exist.</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="webgl"/>
```

I run the test, and  I get not text with  alertMessage.getText() :
   java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "User doesn't exist."
     but: was ""
Expected :User doesn't exist.
Actual   :

My question is do you think the xpath is defined correct?

Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *"...define an xpath to create the webelement for the message text..."* Can you translate this into English?

Comment: My question is do you think the xpath is defined correctly, because I get not text with  alertMessage.getText() : java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "User doesn't exist."
     but: was ""
Expected :User doesn't exist.
Actual   :
 <Click to see difference>

Comment: @IancuMariusGolban Yes. xpath looks correct. However `getText()` is not always good solution. Try `.getAttribute("innerHTML");` instead.

Comment: Hello  @FindBy (xpath = ".//form[@id='login']//div[@class='loginAlert' and @id='loginAlert']")
    private WebElement alertMessage;


  public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)

    { super(driver);
      waitForURLToContains("/login/login");

    }

    public String getLoginAlertMessage()
    {
        wait.until(visibilityOf(alertMessage));
        return alertMessage.getAttribute("innerHTML");

    }

  
        java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of factors as follows :

- You sould try to construct a *logical xpath* as follows :

  ```
  xpath = ".//form[@id='login']//div[@class='loginAlert' and @id='loginAlert']"
  ```
- To extract the text **User doesn't exist.** instead of `getText()` use `getAttribute("innerHTML")`
- Try to use the following *Assertion* :

  ```
  Assert.assertTrue(actualText.contains("User doesn't exist"))
  ```

Comment: The problem is the Xpath is changing in the test, initial is :  <div id="loginAlert" class="loginAlert"/>  and after hit login it changes in the same URL <div id="loginAlert" class="loginAlert">User doesn't exist.</div>.   Please the details in the [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828451/changing-xpath-on-the-same-url-makes-assert-in-login-test-to-fail)